# Adding a dataset in .csv format to TFDS

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, dataset

I am working on the text summarization task and trying to add a .csv dataset to `tensorflow_datasets` (this is required to run a pre-trained transformer). I am following this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset but I still don't get how to add it.

This is what I have so far:

```
import tensorflow_datasets.public_api as tfds

# TODO(data.csv): BibTeX citation
_CITATION = """
"""

_HOMEPAGE = "https:..."

# TODO(data.csv):
_DESCRIPTION = """A textual corpus of ...
"""

_DOCUMENT = "text"
_SUMMARY = "summary"

manual_dir = './'

class new_dataset(tfds.core.GeneratorBasedBuilder):
  """TODO(data.csv): Short description of my dataset."""

  # TODO(data.csv): Set up version.
  VERSION = tfds.core.Version('0.1.0')

  def _info(self):
    return tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
        builder=self,
        description=_DESCRIPTION,
        features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
            _DOCUMENT: tfds.features.Text(),
            _SUMMARY: tfds.features.Text()
        }),
        supervised_keys=(_DOCUMENT, _SUMMARY),
        homepage="https://...",
        citation=_CITATION,
    )

  def _split_generators(self, dl_manager):
    """Returns SplitGenerators."""
    # TODO(data.csv): Downloads the data and defines the splits
    # dl_manager is a tfds.download.DownloadManager that can be used to
    # download and extract URLs
    return [
        tfds.core.SplitGenerator(
            name=tfds.Split.TRAIN,
            # These kwargs will be passed to _generate_examples
            gen_kwargs={},
        ),
    ]

  def _generate_examples(self):
    # Yields examples from the dataset
    yield 'key', {}
```

How to define `def _split_generators` and `def _generate_examples` properly if my dataset is a .csv file with 2 columns: 'text' and 'summary'? This python file and my dataset are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the directions on the Tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset.

0. you have to put your raw csv or txt data in a certain directory order. I made a folder called dataset_DATA, then inside dataset_DATA I made 2 folders (train and test). Then I put dataset_train.csv inside ../dataset_DATA/train and dataset_test.csv inside ../dataset_DATA/test. Then, I zipped the folder dataset_DATA (zip -r dataset_DATA.zip dataset_DATA/)
1. Next I used TFDS CLI and ran (tfds new dataset_name). It created a folder (they call it a project folder) called dataset_name.
2. Next, I created two folders (downloads, downloads/manual) in the dataset_name project folder for storing the manually downloaded data (mkdir /home/path/dataset_name/downloads, mkdir /home/path/dataset_name/downloads/manual). Then, I moved the data to the downloads/manual folder (mv /home/path/dataset_DATA.zip /home/path/dataset_name/downloads/manual).
3. Next, I modified the /home/path/dataset_name/dataset_name_dataset_builder.py file. Below is what I used for text.

> 

```
def _info(self -> tfds.core.DatasetInfo: return self.dataset_info_from_configs(features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({'idx': tfds.features.Scalar(dtype=tf.int32), 'label': tfds.features.ClassLabel(num_classes=3), 'sentence': tfds.features.Text(),}), disable_shuffling=False, homepage='')     def _split_generators(self, dl_manager): tfds.download.DownloadManager): # Way 0: Download from GCP Storage extracted_path = dl_manager.download_and_extract('https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/dataset_DATA.zip') # OR
# Way 1: Manually download the file to the directory, and link to current directory
archive_path = dl_manager.manual_dir/'dataset_DATA.zip'
extracted_path = dl_manager.extract(archive_path)
return {
    'train': self._generate_examples(path=extracted_path/'dataset_DATA/train/dataset_train.csv'), 
    'test': self._generate_examples(path=extracted_path/'dataset_DATA/test/dataset_test.csv')
}
def _generate_examples(self, path):
with path.open() as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        # my csv file has 3 columns ['idx', 'label', 'sentence'] where the first row has the header ['idx', 'label', 'sentence']
        # key = csv file column 'idx' = [0, 1, 2, .., n]
        # csv file column 'label' = [0, 1, or 2]
        # csv file column 'sentence' = ['text0', 'text1', .., 'textn']
        key = row['idx']
        yield key, {'idx': row['idx'], 'label': row['label'], 'sentence': row['sentence']}
```

4. I ran the tfds build command (tfds build --overwrite --data_dir=/home/path/dataset_name/ --download_dir=/home/path/dataset_name/downloads/ --extract_dir=/home/path/dataset_name/downloads/extracted/ --manual_dir=/home/path/dataset_name/downloads/manual --file_format='tfrecord' --publish_dir=/home/path/dataset_name/dataset_name/ /home/path/dataset_name). Be sure to create the extract_dir and publish_dir directories before running tfds or it will give an error (ie: mkdir /home/path/dataset_name/downloads/extracted/).
5. The dataset should be saved in tfrecord format at /home/path/dataset_name/dataset_name/1.0.0. You can use the builder to load dataset (ie: builder = tfds.builder_from_directory('/home/path/dataset_name/dataset_name/1.0.0'), ds = builder.as_dataset(split='train[75%:]')).